# How to setup filter on the table using Authorization in kbmmw

Tags: delphi

How to setup filter on the table using Authorization in kbmmw.

Hi I use kbmMWAuthorizationManager for authorization.

```
| UserA | DataA |
| UserA | DataB |
| UserB | DataC |
```

I need setup filter on the table for field UserA using authorization login.

ADD

I need to call server side query (ALL_EVENTS). I made two events:

```
   procedure TTestQuery.ALL_EVENTSBeforeOpen(DataSet: TDataSet);
   begin
     Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('+');
   end;

   procedure TTestQuery.kbmMWQueryServiceBeforeRequest(const Func: string;
     const ClientIdent: TkbmMWClientIdentity; Args: TkbmMWVariantList);
   begin
     Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add(ClientIdent.Username);
   end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im very unsure about exactly what you want to do.
If you have the username in the table, it by itself can participate in a selection criteria either using SQL or if its memory data table, the OnFilterRecord event for example.
You can always obtain which (already logged in) user is attempting the operation, but looking up the username in the authentication manager via the Token property. Eg.

```
var
  identity:TkbmMWClientIdentity;
begin
...
  identity:=authmgr.Logins.GetClientIdent(yourservice.Token);
  if identity<>Nil then
    username:=identity.UserName
  else
    ...
end;
```

best regards
Kim Madsen
Components4Developers

Comment: Thanks for answer.
But what is yourservice.Token.
I test Autorization demo. Is it TkbmMWInventoryService or kbmMWServer1?

Comment: Ill have to make a longer explanation on this.

Comment: Token is a value assigned at login time, for example by using the TkbmMWAuthorization.Login method. It will return a TkbmMWLoginIdentity instance with a property called Token. 
If you use kbmMWServer in combination with the auth manager, the easiest is to set AutoLogin in Options on the AuthMgr component. Then login process is happening automatically, based on the username/password set on the client side components. After successful login, the client will always send a token instead. The Token is available on any kbmMW service instance.
best regards Kim Madsen/C4D

Comment: The sample Authorization shows how to set it up, and the article "The Authorizationmanager Explained" goes into some details. You can find articles at www.components4developers.com. Click the Docs/Articles menu point to find it and download it. best regards

Comment: I need to call server side query (ALL_EVENTS).

I tested your Authorization demo. 

I added  TTestQuery.ALL_EVENTSBeforeOpen for changing SQL  and .kbmMWQueryServiceBeforeRequest for getting ClientIdent.Username. 

See main request.

After starting I clicked "QUERY ALL" button repeatedly and found that the function  ClientIdent.Username works only once.

Comment: Yes... As mentioned... after login there will be a value in Token instead. You will use the Token to lookup the username.